# Microsoft bot framework - Bot channel Registration. Unable to save the recorded video from skype to Azure storage account

Tags: c#, botframework, skypedeveloper, azure-function-app

For the Microsoft Bot framework chatbot application that I am working on, I have configured the "Bot Channel Registration" and have hosted it on Azure.

One of the scenarios expects the user to record a video on skype and send it as an answer. I have an Azure function that saves the recorded video from skype to the Azure Storage account.

The issue I am encountering is, When I record a video on skype ()via Video Messaging option.

To gain access to the uploaded video from skype, I am providing appropriate bearer token along with the above mentioned URL but failing to get access to it.

Though the file that is uploaded from skype to the Queue (Azure function Queue triggers), the accessibility to this file is denied.

Assuming the latest patches would help, I updated all the references to .NET core 3.0.1 as of today. Looking forward to the desired approach to resolve this.

Note: This issue is only happening in "Skype for Desktop" version.

Below is the code block for your reference.

```
private static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> RequestFile(string contentUrl, ILogger logger, string serviceUrl)
{
    var credentials = DIContainer.Instance.GetService<MicrosoftAppCredentials>();
    var token = await credentials.GetTokenAsync();
    using (var connectorClient = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(serviceUrl), credentials.MicrosoftAppId, credentials.MicrosoftAppPassword))
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"));

            var test = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);

            return test;
        }
    }
}
```

Adding more code snippets:

```
private async Task<(string, string)> TrySaveAndGetContentUrl(IMessageActivity activity, string user)
    {   
        var attachments = activity.Attachments;

        if (attachments?.Any() ?? false)
        {   
            var video = attachments.First();                              
            return (await _attachmentsService.Save(video, user), video.ContentUrl);
        }
        return (null, null);
    }

 ///_attachmentsService.Save method implementation
 public async Task<string> Save(Attachment attachment, string user)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Enqueue save command. {@Attachment}", attachment);

        var blobName = $"{user}/{Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}-{attachment.Name}";
        var blob = _cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);

        await EnqueueSaveCommand(attachment.ContentUrl, blobName, user);

        return blob.Uri.ToString();
    }
```

Please refer the below code block to save the attachments to Azure blob.

```
private async Task EnqueueSaveCommand(string contentUrl, string blobName, string user)
    {
        var queue = _queueClient.GetQueueReference(RouteNames.MediaAttachmentQueue); //RouteNames.MediaAttachmentQueue is "media-attachment-queue"
        await queue.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

        var serializedMessage = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new SaveMediaAttachmentCommand
        {
            FromUrl = contentUrl,
            AttachmentName = blobName,
            UserName = "userid@gmail.com",               
        });

        var queueMessage = new CloudQueueMessage(serializedMessage);

        await queue.AddMessageAsync(queueMessage);
    }
```

[image]
Please suggest.

Comment: Is this your issue? https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/5710

Comment: Kyle, yes it is.

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: yes. it doesn't allow me to save the videos on skype desktop as per the discussion we had. Any suggestions from your end?

Comment: Like I said, I cannot reproduce the issue. You might consider messaging me privately instead of carrying on such a long conversation in comments.

Comment: Ok. Thank you Kyle.

Comment: Are you going to message me?

Answer (score 0):

The Skype channel configuration contains the following message:

> As of October 31, 2019 the Skype channel no longer accepts new Bot publishing requests. This means that you can continue to develop bots using the Skype channel, but your bot will be limited to 100 users. You will not be able to publish your bot to a larger audience. Current Skype bots will continue to run uninterrupted. [Learn more](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/fa12091/why-are-some-features-not-available-in-skype-anymore)

Many Skype features have been deprecated. If it was ever possible to send a video to a bot over Skype, it may not be possible any longer. It's recommended that you switch to other channels like Direct Line and Microsoft Teams.

Comment: This issue only happens with Skype for Desktop version! With Skype Microsoft app version, the videos are uploaded perfectly as expected. 
Is it something I need to consider to make it work for "Skype for Desktop"?

Comment: @RajeshNagendra - This could be a client-specific feature. The mobile client and the desktop client seem to be very different and they might handle attachments differently. You could try uploading a video file with "Add files" instead of "Video Message" but I don't know if that will work and generally you should not expect to get any support for deprecated channels.

Comment: As you mentioned, Adding video files worked fine. 
But when we use "Video Message" option, It fails to upload the recorded video.  The content type is mentioned as application/octet-stream. (I also tried video/mp4 which did not work). The issue is only while using "Video Message" Option.

Comment: So your bot is getting the video attachment after all? What do you want your bot to do with the video? I cannot possibly help you if you won't give me the information of what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: Here is the scenario.. I schedule a initial screening for an interview. So the candidate would record his answers with "Video Message" option and send them as an answer to the interview questions. (Note: The earlier recorded video is not preferred way to answer the interview questions.)

Comment: Kyle, Any inputs on my previous response?

Comment: You will need to either update your question or ask a new question with the code you're using to save the video to Azure storage. Even if there is a way for the bot to receive the video message, it won't do you any good if I try to tell you how to save it in a way that doesn't work with your Azure function.

Comment: kyle, I have updated the same question with the code snippet I have been using. Please check.

Comment: There appears to have been a misunderstanding here. You added a code block that appears to have had a lot of relevant code removed, since you're declaring unused `token` and `connectorClient` variables and you're using a `uri` variable that isn't defined anywhere. But more importantly, this isn't what I asked for. You said your bot is receiving a video as an attachment of an activity in the Skype channel, but you only know how to consume the attachment when its content type is not application/octet-stream. I need you to show me what you're doing with an attachment you get from the mobile app.

Comment: Added the code blocks. Please let me know if you require any other details.

Comment: The code you provided is mostly what I was looking for, but I still need to know one thing. What is `EnqueueSaveCommand` doing with the content URL? Is your Azure blob just saving the URL, or is the whole video getting stored in the Azure blob? Would you be satisfied with a solution that uploaded your video somewhere else and then just passed the URL to the Azure blob, or do you need the video to be uploaded to the blob?

Comment: EnqueueSaveCommand metnod, saved the attachment to the Azure blob. AI am saving the whole video on the blob. As this scenraio is only failing on "Skype for desktop", it good to save the file on azure blob. In case if this isn't feasible, I prefer to achieve it by saving the URL. Video uploaded to blob is the ideal case.

Comment: @RajeshNagendra - Okay but just to make sure I'm doing things the same way you are, can you show the code that's accessing the Azure blob API to actually do the uploading?

Comment: @RajeshNagendra - It turns out that when I send a video to my bot in Skype desktop using the video message button, it gets sent as an attachment of type "video" the same as if I use the attachment button or Skype mobile. Can you tell me what version of Skype desktop you're using? Also, have you possibly modified some Skype settings that might make Skype send video messages differently?

Comment: It is Skype version 8.55.0.141. Its just default settings on skype desktop. I have not changed any settings on skype.

Comment: @RajeshNagendra - Well there has to be something different between what you're doing and what I'm doing. Perhaps you're using a different button from the video message button that I'm talking about, so you could try posting screenshots of what you're doing. Otherwise, if you want to upvote and accept this answer then you can email me with private details about how to repro this issue, like by screen sharing.

Comment: Please find the attached screenshot. I would be happy to share the screen and show u the issue. Please let me know.

Comment: @RajeshNagendra - Well that is the correct video message button. I thought maybe you were getting an octet stream because you were trying to call the bot or something. Anyway, I'm pretty lost about what the issue might be, but it's up to you if you want to email me or not. Remember that you can do troubleshooting on your end more easily than I can, since I don't have access to your machine. You can try to come up with possibilities about what the difference might be between your environment and mine. Perhaps we're using different operating systems. Volunteer information to find a solution.

Comment: I shall email you and share the screen in your free time. Currently, I am on my windows Machine and have faced issue. Are you using Windows  or mac?

Comment: As per the discussion over screen sharing session, I debugged using ngrok and it just gives me the status code as false. I  am continuing to find out alternatives. Will keep you posted on the status. thank you for your inputs.